# How can I output the value of a concat value of scss?

Tags: sass

When I have something like below

```
#{'$station-position-#{$station}'}
```

it outputs as

```
$station-position-1934
```

But I want it to output the value of $station-position-1969 . How can I do that?

Comment: please try this $station: 969

Comment: Nope.. Sorry . You have misunderstood.. It is created dynamically. That is why I have the #{'$station-position-#{$station}'} . #{'$station-position-#{$station}'} gives me the $station-position-1934 or some other radom number like $station-position-969. But by that $station-position-1934 is also a varibale in scss.. so need to output that

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a variable `$station-position-12` which say has a value of `red` and a `$station` variable which has a value of `12` and you want to **interpolate** `$station-position-#{station}` to be interpreted as the variable `$station-position-12` which will then use the value of `red`. This unfortunately is **NOT** possible in Sass.

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to do but you could use `maps` where maybe the `station` value could be the _map key_ and the `station-position-station` could be the _map value_

Answer (score 1):

Are you depending on your nested variables?
If not you can try structuring your data using scss lists.

Examples:
http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists/